# Integrate maven jsp/webapp project with eclipse

Tags: jsp, m2eclipse, m2e, eclipse-wtp, m2e-wtp

What is the current approach to integrate a maven webapp project with eclipse to get context-sensitive java-code support in jsp-files?

In eclipse-luna, I can use the maven wizard with maven-archetype-webapp, to create the project, and it works OK.

But, if I then check in the maven project with pom.xml (but without .settings, .project files) in version-control,
then somebody else checks it out and imports it as Maven => "existing maven project" into eclipse, 
it does not recognize java-snippets <% ... %> in the jsp-files as java-code, but just treats it as plain text.

I found instead you can do:

```
maven eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

and import as "Existing eclipse project", which seems to work, but I get the impression this is quite out-dated approach today (only supports wtp up to version 2.0).

Therefore, what is the right way to get this working properly both in maven and in eclipse?